# Can I overload 'operator new' with a different return type?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

Here's my situation:  I want to overload "operator new" so that instead of allocating my object in a random space in memory, it gets allocated in a pre-defined memory buffer.  I want to be able to save this buffer to a file and load it in the future, so I want to use handles instead of pointers.  What I want, ideally, is for "operator new" to return a handle that I can use to go straight to the object's place in it's buffer.  Is it possible to do this in C++(11)?  If not, what are my best alternatives?

Comment: Why don't you just store the informations to construct your object in the file? I don't know anything about handle, as this has nothing to do with C++, but you can still return a normal pointer and when you read the file copy the content to your buffer then simply cast it... That's really an undefined behavior and a really easy way to hack your program though...

Comment: Because I want to be able to save the entire system to a file in one batch, without having to serialize every last pointer for what could realistically be tens, if not hundreds of thousands of references.  By using handles (an index into the array which stores the objects), I can avoid countless serialization bugs before they happen.

Comment: If each object serialize itself and you have a deserialization constructor, then it's not a problem. And according to your definition, your handle is an offset to a pointer, so a pointer can do exactly the same job.

Comment: @Geoffroy No, it would still be a problem if there's any virtual functions in the object.  The amount of space needed would differ across CPU platforms and compilers, as would padding.  Even worse if it ever gets run on 32 bit and 64 bit processors.  You never want to write an object directly to a file.

Comment: @GabeSechan That's why I was talking about storing information to construct the object.

Comment: I fully intend to have both a 32-bit and 64-bit version of my executable, and I would like to be able to share files between them.

Comment: Why not have a function do it, rather than try to change the meaning of a `operator new` allocator or a new-expression?

Comment: @aschepler I considered that, and if what I want to do turns out impossible, I'll do exactly that.  I just want to use 'operator new' for eloquence.

Comment: "Because I want to be able to save the entire system to a file in one batch": this is fundamentally impossible.  There is no standard representation for most types.

Comment: No, AFAIK, however you can make `std::allocator<T>::allocate` return whatever you want. (Just don't expect it to work with containers, etc. out-of-the-box).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik you cannot change the return type of the `new` operator. For your scenario you could try the following approach:

1. Define a `Handle` (or `Handle<T>`, if you need handles for more than one type) class, which internally stores the index into your allocation area (i.e. `Handle` has one single member variable `index`). The `Handle` class will need to internally somehow have access to your allocation subsystem, i.e. it will need to know where the actual storage area (buffer) is located.
2. Define a constructor for `Handle` taking a pointer (returned by your `new` implementation) as argument and computing the index from that (e.g. by subtracting the beginning of your storage area)
3. Also define a dereferencing operator (`operator *`) for the `Handle` class returning a reference to the "handled" object (e.g. by adding the index to the beginning of the storage area...)
4. In your code, alsways use `Handle<T>` instead of pointers to `T`, at least at every point where you actually *store* the Handle/pointer.

That way, when you serialize/deserialize your storage area, only indices will be written to the disk. Using the `Handle` class will be the same as using pointers. The computation of the actual pointers will be done internally.

Of course this will have some performance penalty, since instead of directly using pointers there will always be some computation. Also this might affect the optimization that can be done by the compiler. One idea to minimize this performance issue would be to implement a conversion operator from `Handle<T>` to `T*`, so for code pieces that use a single Handle/Pointer a lot you could easily "precompute" the pointer and use it throughout the code.

Answer (score 0):

I know something that might help you.. Try this..

Standard C++ also supports a second version of new, called placement new, which constructs an object on a preallocated storage. In order for this to work we must provide the address where we want the object to be allocated as a pointer parameter:

(my_class = new (place) Myclass);

So why would you want to use placement new? Placement new is useful for constructing objects in a pre-allocated block of memory. This bypasses the work of operator new by allowing the person constructing the object to choose the memory that it is initialized into. You might do this if you have a pool of memory you want to use for constructing some objects of a class, but don't want to overload operator new for the whole class.

Comment: I think the problem here is when the OP stores pointers to the created objects (e.g. links objects together). When he simply serializes the whole memory block of all allocated objects, after deserialization the pointers will be invalid since the deserialized memory block will likely be at another location.